# ASP.NET MVC 5 RegularExpression Attribute Failing For Password Validation

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

This is my regular expression:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^((?=.{12,}$)(?=[^\d]*\d)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^\W]*\W))", ErrorMessage = "Passwords must be at least 12 characters long and contain at least an upper case letter, lower case letter, digit and a symbol")]
```

**Criteria:**

12 characters long with at least one lower case letter, upper case letter and special character.

**String is rejected when:**

Any string less than 12 characters,

aaaaaaaaaaaa,

aaaaaaaaaaaa1

**String is accepted (should be rejected) when:**

aaaaaaaaaaaaA,

aaaaaaaaaaaa#

Edit: This is my code for the password getter and setter in the model.

```
[Required]   
[RegularExpression("^(?=.{12,}$)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@!%*?&,#]).+$", ErrorMessage = "Passwords must be at least 12 characters long and contain at least an upper case letter, lower case letter, digit and a symbol")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Comment: Does your password contains a digit as there error message contains digit also `"Passwords must be at least 12 characters long and contain at least an upper case letter, lower case letter, digit and a symbol"`

Comment: @SwapNeil Oh yes, I thought I had done so originally?

Comment: What exactly are your test cases? Those above do not fit your criteria. If the criteria are followed, you need `^(?=\D*\d)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^_\W]*[_\W]).{12,}$` - see https://regex101.com/r/aM2bgd/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Those were the strings that I tried. To be clear, they should all fail, I will update the question for clarity.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried yours on my MVC application and the same test cases were accepted when they shouldn't have been. There must be a fundemental error in my application which could be causing this, as both Regexes should work.

Comment: I think you should show more of your code.

Comment: Are you using `@Html.PasswordFor` or `@Html.TextBoxFor`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Your Criteria:**

12 characters long with at least one lower case letter, upper case letter and special character.

**Note:** I have added a digit also as your validation message contains digit.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{12,}", ErrorMessage = "Passwords must be at least 12 characters long and contain at least an upper case letter, lower case letter, digit and a symbol")]
```

Comment: I tried it and it passed and failed the original test cases.

Comment: I tried the given test case and it didn't pass `aaaaaaaaaaaa, aaaaaaaaaaaa1 aaaaaaaaaaaaA,  aaaaaaaaaaaa#`

Comment: That is very odd, I have tried both yours and WiktorStribiżew's Regex, yet it still accepts the final two test cases. Very unsure as to why.

Answer (score 0):

`[RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{12,}", ErrorMessage = "Passwords must be at least 12 characters long and contain at least an upper case letter, lower case letter, digit and a symbol")]`

The answer given by @SwapNeil is correct.

You could try it out here: https://regex101.com/

If it still is not working. Kindly check whether the ~/bundles/jqueryval is included in the view.